# StringTokennizer, take only the last 3 elements out of 4

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I need some help to figure this problem i have run into. Have read a txt file with a buffer reader and trying to use a StringTokenizer.
The string i have it like this, where some text first and some numbers after. I only need to numbers, and want to skip "Text".

```
Test 2 5 1
```

**My code:**

```
// Check if the graph contains an cycle
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    Graph.checkForCycle(null, Integer.parseInt(st1.()), Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken()));
```

As you can see there are 4 sets here and i want the last 3 to be send with the paramenter when i call the method Graph.checkForCycle()

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to throw out the first one:

```
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
st1.nextToken(); // "Text" - do nothing with it
int i1 = Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken()); // 2
// ...
Graph.checkForCycle(null, i1, i2, i3);
```

Alternatively, you can use Scanner that takes care of the conversion:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(br.readLine());
sc.next(); // "Text"
int i1 = sc.nextInt();
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As of java 1.5, sun (now it's oracle) discouraged the use of StringTokenizer.

So in the StringTokenizer's javadoc, it is said :

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

However, it is not mentionned that you can also use the Scanner class.

Example with String's split method :

```
String[] args = br.readLine().split("\\s");  // Split on whitespaces
Graph.checkForCycle(null, args[1], args[2], args[3]);
```

Example with the java.util.Scanner class :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(br.readLine());
scanner.next();  //skip the first
Graph.checkForCycle(null, scanner.next(), scanner.next(), scanner.next());
```

These are juste brief examples, don't use them as is.  ie : you'll want to use the method "hasNext" in case the number of words in the text line can vary.